# How can I implement a Deterministic finite automaton which accepts

Tags: automata, finite-automata

**Problem**: implement a Deterministic finite automaton which accepts 01 ∪ (2∪10*2)*

∪ <- is union symbol

I have a lot of problem trying to implement that DFA, the union symbol always confuse me
Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Berry-Sethi's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov%27s_construction_algorithm) for the general method (+ [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) for a DFA).